# additional variable into php array output?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I have the following script currently, which gets the category IDs as arrays:

```
$sql_select_categories = $db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories 
                                     WHERE parent_id='" . intval($src_details['parent_id']) . "' 
                                     ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC"); 

$additional_vars = set_filter_link($src_details, array('parent_id' => '', 'start' => ''), 'address');

while ($cat_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_categories)) {
    $cat_array[$cat_details['category_id']]["name"] = $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']];
}

if(is_array($cat_array)) {  
    asort($cat_array);

    foreach($cat_array as $key => $value) {     
        $subcat_link = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?parent_id=' . $key . $additional_vars;

        $output .= '<tr> '.
        '   <td class="contentfont">&nbsp;&raquo; <a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$key] . '</a></td> '.
        '</tr> ';
    }
}   
return $output;
```

This works perfectly, except I need to extract one more variable from the database which is called `count`. So the MySQL query will change from

```
SELECT category_id FROM
```

to

```
SELECT category_id, count FROM
```

So far so good, but how do I get it to then display each of the counts in the `foreach`? I need them displayed in the HTML after `$category_lang[$key]` as something like `$count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$cat_details` array will have another element that you can reference, which will be `$cat_details['count']`. You can then add that to your `$cat_array` like you do with that name element in the `while` loop.

```
$cat_array[ $cat_details['category_id'] ]['count'] = $cat_details['count'];
```

Make sense?

Comment: First of all thank you! Makes sense but something isn't working :( Do I add the $cat_array for the count as a 2nd line? Or somehow build it into the other one. Sorry, I just started learning with arrays and it's all very complicated!

Comment: Do I change it to something like this?

Comment: I got it working by adding another line of $cat_array below the other one. I printed the entire array in my browser and I see it's working, but can't figure out how to then print it as a $value.

Comment: It now displays the values as:

[215] => Array ( [name] => Category Name [items_counter] => 19 )

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Each `$value` will be an array, as well, so you will reference `$value['count']` in the output `foreach` loop.